# Create a wpa_supplicant UI

Tags: c, unix, wifi, wifi-direct, wpa-supplicant

I need to create a program who communicate with direct wifi between a litle card and a android. I have done a "iw list" and i got :
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
So, normally, that should do it.
I have found this web-site : https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/index.html to use wpa_applicant in a c code.
So, I used like they said wpa_ctrl.c
   CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "direct.h"
#include "wpa_ctrl.h"
#include <string.h>

void    function_test_call(char *msg, size_t len)
{
printf("message callback %s\n", msg);
printf("len callback %d\n", len);

}

int main()
{
struct  wpa_ctrl *wpa_path;

const char *path = "/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0";

wpa_path = (void*)0;
wpa_path = wpa_ctrl_open(path);
if (wpa_path)
{
    printf("youpi\n");
}
else
{
    printf("pas youpi\n");
    return (1);
}
char response[1024];
size_t size_buf = 0;
int ret = wpa_ctrl_request(wpa_path, "PING",
4, response, &size_buf, function_test_call);
printf("ret value %d\n", ret);
printf("response size %d\n", size_buf);
printf("reponse : %s\n", response);
return (0);
}
```

this is what's append when i run :
youpi
ret value 0
response size 0
reponse :

So the connection is ok, but the REQUEST ping should be PONG or i got nothing.
Please help me :)

Comment: `wpa_path = (void*)0;` as opposed to `wpa_path = NULL;`? Just curious why you'd want to cast `0`...

Comment: It's stupid I know. :), It's just m'y way how i do thing... Maybe not the best way ..

Comment: @Aodren BARY were u able to supply pin to P2P GO,when the P2P client provided u pin to be enter on the other device.

Answer (score 1):

I found, it's my mistake 
 I replaced
    size_t size_buf = 0;
    size_t size_buf = 1023;
My bad -_-